# python logging.info does not print, logging.warn and logging.error does

Tags: python

```
import logging

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.info('info')
    logging.warn('warning')
    logging.error('error')
```

Result:

```
warning
error
```

Why does `logging.info` not report anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your log level is set so that 'info' won't print; by default it doesn't print anything less than WARNING. See [Logger.setLevel](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.setLevel).